# Given the ItemClick event on a GridView, how do I know the group that was clicked?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime

I have a GridView that displays grouped items (similar to the default project on Win8 store apps).

The difference is that each group may contain the same items as others.

I need to know, for the item, which  group it was clicked in.

[Edit: Removed "item was clicked"]

**I know how work around the issue by walking the visual tree (and not using the ItemClick event) - but I want to know if there's a standard way for doing that.**

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the default SampleDataSource class? If you are, in the ItemView_ItemClick event, you can get the ID for the group using the following code

```
        var groupId = ((SampleDataItem)e.ClickedItem).Group;
```

Comment: In my question, I say that "each group may contain the same items as others". That means that I can't have a .Group property.